# Identificar si una librería está compilada en modo release o debug en .NET

Tags: c#, .net

¿Cuál es la manera de saber si una dll está compilada en modo release o debug en .NET?
He tratado de averiguarlo por google y usando ILDSAM, pero no me queda muy claro.

Comment: Hola Sergio, algún lenguaje en particular?, mira mi respuesta, esta en C#.

Comment: Necesitas averiguarlo programáticamente o te basta con revisar el assembly con algún SW?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Debes consultar los atributos del assembly (o dll de .net o ensamblado)

```
public bool IsAssemblyDebugBuild(Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                   .OfType<DebuggableAttribute>()
                   .Select(da => da.IsJITTrackingEnabled)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Explicación:

[`DebuggableAttribute.IsJITTrackingEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.isjittrackingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) es el truco, pues esta en verdadero si se ha generado la información de depuración.

Nota: Cuando ejecutas el proyecto desde el compilador puede no funcionar. Intenta ejecutarlo desde la linea de comandos.

#### Luego lo usarías así:

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.Load("nombre"); // si el assembly se llama nombre.dll
if (IsAssemblyDebugBuild(dll)) {
   // fue compilado en modo debug.
}
```

*la función IsAssemblyDebugBuild la he tomado del sito en ingles [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186634/2573335).*

#### Edición:

En este repositorio te dejo un ejemplo que funciona. Ejecútalo en modo Debug y Release para ver como es.

**https://github.com/rnrneverdies/IsAssemblyDebugBuild.git**

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dijiste en tus comentarios, esta la opción:

[`DebuggableAttribute.IsJITOptimizerDisabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.isjitoptimizerdisabled(v=vs.110).aspx) pero ten en cuenta que puede dar falsos positivos en Relese si se quitan las optimizaciones.

Comment: la función IsAssemblyDebugBuild siempre me devuelve true. No me devuelve si la librería ha sigo compilada en debug o en reléase.

Comment: @SergioGarcia dame unos minutos

Comment: @rnrnerverdies IsAssemblyDebugBuild sólo devuelve false si añado la siguiente línea en el AssemblyInfo del proyecto de pruebas que he realizado (en lugar de usar assembly.Load uso Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly): "<Assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.None)> " Aunque de momento no sé muy bien que implicaciones tiene. Usando IsJITOptimizerDisabled que he sacado de la respuesta de Leandro Tuttini funciona.

Comment: @SergioGarcia acabo de probarlo y funciona bien. ahora te comparto el projecto de prueba en GitHub. Si compilas el projecto en modo debug o release, lo indica.

Comment: @SergioGarcia te recomiendo que lo pruebes desde la linea de comando y no desde el compilador pues no funcionara de la misma manera.

Comment: lo miraré y te digo algo, ahora estoy tratando de aclarar qué diferencia hay entre IsJITOptimizerDisabled e IsJITTrackingEnabled. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 4):

La forma mas fácil y rápida es usando [ILDASM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx)

Para ejecutarlo solo abre la la consola de desarrollo de Visual Studio y ejecuta el comando ILDASM

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>ildasm
```

Luego abre tu .exe o .dll y busca un método cualquiera y dale doble clic y trata de buscar la instrucción `nop` en el código descompilado

Si encuentras instrucciones `nop` entre las otras instrucciones quiere decir que fue compilado en modo `DEBUG` si no encuentras ninguna fue en modo `RELEASE`.

Ejemplo:

Para el siguiente código:

```
using System;

namespace DebugReleaseTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Esta es una prueba");
        }
    }
}
```

Al abrir el `.exe` compilado como `DEBUG` obtenemos esto:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Esta es una prueba"
  IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_000b:  nop
  IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Mientras que en modo `RELEASE` obtenemos lo sgte:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "Esta es una prueba"
  IL_0005:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Nótese los `nop` antes y después del `Console::WriteLine`

Answer (score 2):

Un excelente articulo sobre el tema

[How to Tell if an Assembly is Debug or Release](http://dave-black.blogspot.com.ar/2011/12/how-to-tell-if-assembly-is-debug-or.html)

Segun entiendo al compilar debermos tomar los datos del `DebuggableAttribute` para luego conocer el valor del `IsJITOptimizerDisabled`  indicando si el codigo esta optimizado o no

```
object[] attribs = ReflectedAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), false);

// If the 'DebuggableAttribute' is not found then it is definitely an OPTIMIZED build
if (attribs.Length > 0)
{
    // Just because the 'DebuggableAttribute' is found doesn't necessarily mean
    // it's a DEBUG build; we have to check the JIT Optimization flag
    // i.e. it could have the "generate PDB" checked but have JIT Optimization enabled
    DebuggableAttribute debuggableAttribute = attribs[0] as DebuggableAttribute;
    if (debuggableAttribute != null)
    {
        HasDebuggableAttribute = true;
        IsJITOptimized = !debuggableAttribute.IsJITOptimizerDisabled;
        BuildType = debuggableAttribute.IsJITOptimizerDisabled ? "Debug" : "Release";

        // check for Debug Output "full" or "pdb-only"
            DebugOutput = (debuggableAttribute.DebuggingFlags &
                            DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default) !=
                            DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.None
                            ? "Full" : "pdb-only";
    }
}
else
{
    IsJITOptimized = true;
    BuildType = "Release";
}
```

La linea mas importante seria

```
BuildType = debuggableAttribute.IsJITOptimizerDisabled ? "Debug" : "Release";
```

indicando si esta optimizada la compilacion

Cuando usa la linea

```
object[] attribs = ReflectedAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), false);
```

en  `ReflectedAssembly` seria el assembly que queremos evaluar, podrias usar el `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` o cargar alguna otra libreria externa para evaluar